Select month from timestamp and revenue
I am looking to respond to this type of question "For the month of September, how many orders did store A receive? What was the total revenue from these orders?"
The date I have is a timestamp such as YYYY-MM-DD.
What i have so far is this :
Select order_id as orders,
MONTHNAME(date) as month name,
order_value
from table.orders
where month name = '09'
GROUP BY orders
I have no way to test it as it is a theoretical question, please help

For validation of simple exercises like this, using a simple online SQL fiddle would suffice.
To Validate the SQL query you would need to create a table, insert some dummy values and then execute the query.
Something like this.

thank you! and so for total revenue i would need to format it like this ?
SELECT
COUNT(DISTINCT order_id) AS total_orders,
SUM(order_value) AS total_revenue
FROM
orders
WHERE
store_name = 'Store A'
AND Month(date) = 9
Would that work?

Yes, it would. That fiddle is editable, so you can write your queries there and try them out.
If you could mark my answer as the solution, it would be greatly appreciated!
